# setInterval that changes innerHTML seems to interfere with EventListener?

Tags: javascript

I have an interesting behavior where a timer that's changing innerHTML of a div seems to invalidate a previously added EventListener. Should I be re-adding the EventListener every time innerHTML gets updated?

If you wait 5 seconds on the JSFiddle and then try to click 'Settings' nothing will happen ...

HTML:

```
<div class="header left font13" id="setup">Settings</div>
<div class="header mid font13" id="wtime"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("setup").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Settings!");
});

setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Alive!");
  document.getElementById("wtime").innerHTML = "11:45".replaceAll(":", "<span class='blink'>:</span>");
}, 5000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pog0h29t/

Comment: Because both your `.header` elements are absolutely positioned, and thus the new one (`#wtime`)  is on top of the one you've attached the click handler on. At first it doesn't have content and thus no height either. When you set content to it, it will catch the click event instead of `#setup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eventlistener is working fine. This is not a JS problem, but a CSS problem. Your wtime thing is block the Settings div.

[image]

Comment: Ahh yes, that's it, I have to z-index it :)